# Google bots and iframe

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt, googlebot, iframe, subdirectory

Here is the problem:

Let say I have `mydomain.com`. The `externaldomain.com/article/mydomain` has an `iframe` with `mydomain.com` inside but the `externaldomain.com` *robots.txt* contains:

```
Disallow: /article/
```

Will Google crawl `mydomain.com` inside the `iframe` at `externaldomain.com/article/mydomain` or it will block `mydomain.com`, because `externaldomain.com` *robots.txt* disallow the folder `/article`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Disallow: /article/` will block the URL (or page) `article/` and all subfolders or subpages.

That's why, if the *robots.txt* of `externaldomain.com` applies this directive for the user agent is `googlebot`, don't worry.

Here are [Google instructions](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156449?hl=en.) on this.

Comment: So does the iframe in /article/mydomain pointed on mydomain.com will also block?

Comment: `/article/mydomain` is considered as a subpage; therefore, it's blocked by _robots.txt_.

Comment: ok does the google provide a document regarding that?

Comment: I have edited my answer to give you the link to Google support in this subject.